# Can't create project with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to create project with Composer using command

`composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter myproject`

and i get this Exception

`[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package codeigniter4/appstarter with stability stable in a version installable using your PHP version 5.6.40.`

Comment: You say you are using wamp with PHP 7.3.12 but the error clearly says the package doesn't work with PHP 5.6.40. Seems there is some disconnect with the version compose uses and wamp. What is the output of `php --version`? How did you install composer?

Comment: I installed composer on with installer for windows, didn't use developer mode installation. Output of  `php --version` says I am using PHP 5.6.40. But on Wamp server and when I run `phpinfo()` it says that I am using PHP 7.3.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited Path variable, changed path to php from `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40` to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12` and it worked.